# Select by Attributes With OR Operator

Tags: qgis

I know this is a very basic question, but I've been looking for an answer and haven't been able to find one, so here it goes. I am trying to build a long query to select features that have different values in the same field, in order to make it as agile as poossible. All in one selection.

Example: In a given attribute table, in the field "H1" select features that have values "31p", "34n", "61f" and "31q" in it.

```
"H1"  =  '31p'  OR  '34n'  OR  '61f'  OR  '31q' 
"H1"  =  '31p'  OR  "H1"  =  '34n'  OR  "H1"  =  '61f'  OR  = '31q'
```

None of them work. Should I use "IS" logical operator instead of "="?

Answer (score 9):

You should repeat the column name for each value in the query

```
"H1" = '31p' or "H1" = '34n' ...
```

You had better to use "in" operator like

```
"H1" in ('31p', '34n', '31q', '61f')
```

Comment: The first way you suggested doesn't work (I had already tried). But I was able to do it with the "in" operator. Thanks

Comment: I put here the whole expression: "H1"  =  '31p'  OR "H1"  =  '34n'  OR  "H1"  = '61f'  OR "H1"  =  '31q' it will work.